# Observable streams - one to many vs many to one

Tags: rxjs, observable, ngxs

How to store a list of **items** when items can exist in different modules?

**One state** to items or **Multi states** to items?
I assume there will be a lot of different modules that will store items and the more of these modules, the more I want to move away from one state

### One state

```ts
class Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  location: "equipment" | "magazine" | "shop"  // | and other in future...
}

class AppState {
  items: Item[];
}

const getItems = (store: Store): Observable<Item[]> => {
  return store.select((appStore: AppStore) => appStore.items);
}

const getItemsInEquipment = (store: Store): Observable<Item[]> => {
  const items$: Observable<Item[]> = getItems(store);
  return items$.pipe(
    map(items => items.filter(item => item.location === "equipment"))
  );
}

const getItemsInMagazine = (store: Store): Observable<Item[]> => {
  const items$: Observable<Item[]> = getItems(store);
  return items$.pipe(
    map(items => items.filter(item => item.location === "magazine"))
  );
}

const getItemsInShop = (store: Store): Observable<Item[]> => {
  const items$: Observable<Item[]> = getItems(store);
  return items$.pipe(
    map(items => items.filter(item => item.location === "shop"))
  );
}
```

or...

### Multi states

```ts
class Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

class AppState {
  itemsInEquipment: Item[];
  itemsInMagazine: Item[];
  itemsInShop: Item[];
  // | and other in future...
}

const getItemsInEquipment = (store: Store): Observable<Item[]> => {
  return store.select((appStore: AppStore) => appStore.itemsInEquipment);
}

const getItemsInMagazine = (store: Store): Observable<Item[]> => {
  return store.select((appStore: AppStore) => appStore.itemsInMagazine);
}

const getItemsInShop = (store: Store): Observable<Item[]> => {
  return store.select((appStore: AppStore) => appStore.itemsInShop);
}

const getItems = (store: Store): Observable<Item[]> => {
  const itemsInEquipment$: Observable<Item[]> = getItemsInEquipment(store);
  const itemsInMagazine$:  Observable<Item[]> = getItemsInMagazine(store);
  const itemsInShop$:      Observable<Item[]> = getItemsInShop(store);
  return combineLatest([itemsInEquipment$, itemsInMagazine$, itemsInShop$]);
}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both approaches?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a different approach. In NgRx, for example, we would set up a single Entity state for all `Items`, and then simply store arrays of the IDs of the `Items` in each list. NGXS Labs has an Entity state adapter that might be worth trying.

Basically, you have all of your `Items` stored in an Object, where the keys are the `id` field for each `Item`:

```js
itemEntities: {
  itemId1: Item,
  itemId2: Item,
  itemId3: Item
}
```

This allows for direct lookup, and prevents performance losses caused by Array actions.

Then, each of your `itemsInEquipment`, `itemsInStore` etc are all simple Arrays of  `ids`, allowing you to grab them from the Entity state.